# android sqlite fts case insensitive

Tags: android, sqlite, unicode, fts3

I'm using SQLite FTS3 tables in my application. But search with FTS table is case sensitive for non English characters.

Is there simple way to make case insensitive search support for unicode symbols?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you insert value in FTS table insert it in lower case. When you query matches convert your word to lower case too!

Comment: Yes. I did it in such way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sqlite started support unicode61 tokenizer for fts index, which would help in this case.
http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#unicode61